# It is possible to store a dojo validator function into a variable to invoke it later

Tags: javascript, validation, dojo, xpages

To customize a validator of dojo NumberTextBox, dojo ValidationTextBox... I need to store the default validator somewhere in the js context and to be able to invoke it later ; the custom validation depends on the result of the default validator.

It is possible to do it in this way and can you help me doing it ?

Thanks a lot

A sample of code :

```
var djNumberTextBox1 = dijit.byId('#{id:djNumberTextBox1}');
djNumberTextBox1.validator = function() {
    var valide = true;

//here I'd like to invoke the default (old) validator (something like next line)
//var valide = djNumberTextBox1.validate();//but this causes a too much recursion because validate() references the current function

//customisation depending on the default (old) validator result
var djButton1 = dijit.byId('#{id:djButton1}');
if(!valide){
    djButton1.setDisabled(true);
}else{
    djButton1.setDisabled(false);
}

return valide;};
```

Comment: please provide a sample of the code so I can post a more specific solution Thanks

Comment: a sample of code has been added. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try the following code:

```
var djNumberTextBox1 = dijit.byId('#{id:djNumberTextBox1}');

// store the validator in _oldValidator
djNumberTextBox1._oldValidator = djNumberTextBox1.validator;

djNumberTextBox1.validator = function() {
    var valide = true;


    // Run the old validator
    valide = djNumberTextBox1._oldValidator();

//customisation depending on the default (old) validator result
var djButton1 = dijit.byId('#{id:djButton1}');
if(!valide){
    djButton1.setDisabled(true);
}else{
    djButton1.setDisabled(false);
}

return valide;};
```

**Edit 1**:
Passed arguments to the validator function.

```
var djNumberTextBox1 = dijit.byId('#{id:djNumberTextBox1}');

// store the validator in _oldValidator
djNumberTextBox1._oldValidator = djNumberTextBox1.validator;

djNumberTextBox1.validator = function(value, constraints) {
    var valide = true;


    // Run the old validator with arguments
    valide = djNumberTextBox1._oldValidator(value, constraints);

//customisation depending on the default (old) validator result
var djButton1 = dijit.byId('#{id:djButton1}');
if(!valide){
    djButton1.setDisabled(true);
}else{
    djButton1.setDisabled(false);
}

return valide;};
```

**Edit 2**:
I think for NumberTextBox the validate() is called.

```
var djNumberTextBox1 = dijit.byId('#{id:djNumberTextBox1}');

// store the validate in _oldValidate
djNumberTextBox1._oldValidate = djNumberTextBox1.validate;

djNumberTextBox1.validate = function() {
    var valide = true;

    // Run the old validate
    valide = djNumberTextBox1._oldValidate();

//customisation depending on the default (old) validate result
var djButton1 = dijit.byId('#{id:djButton1}');
if(!valide){
    djButton1.setDisabled(true);
}else{
    djButton1.setDisabled(false);
}

return valide;};
```

Comment: After testing with your code, "djNumberTextBox1._oldValidator()" returns always false

Comment: It seems to be working well for "ValidationTextBox", but it don't works for "NumberTextBox" It seems like the validator used by NumberTextBox is a different of "djNumberTextBox1.validator".
Use case : when typing chars into a NumberTextBox, the message error is shown but not from the custom validator function

Comment: I too am new to dojo so tryin to help u to the best of my abilities. can you try out my first solution for NumberTextBox with some adjustments. Replace `djNumberTextBox1.validator` with `djNumberTextBox1.validate`. so `djNumberTextBox1._oldValidator = djNumberTextBox1.validator;` becomes `djNumberTextBox1._oldValidate = djNumberTextBox1.validate;` and change `validator` to `validate` likewise. See if it helps. see my **Edit 2**.

Comment: I just found that your solution **Edit 1** works also for "NumberTextBox", the difference is that it is invoked after exiting the NumberTextBox input (onBlur) and this is good for my need.

Conclusion : with the ValidationTextBox the validator is invoked while typing (onChange or onKeyUp...), and with NumberTextBox it is invoked after typing (onBlur)

Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use use 'single tone object', or a property of the current object to add any information usefull for "validation" and re-access the value when you need it from NumberTextBox.